# How to refer to class attribute when setting ItemsSource

Tags: c#, list, class, object, binding

I want to bind `TabItems` from list to `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl Name="TabsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

TabObject is generated in code behind:

```
private List<TabObject> tabsList = new List<TabObject>();    
TabObject MyTab = new TabObject(Tabitem tabitem, object genericObject);
tabsList.Add(MyTab);
TabsControl.DataContext = tabList
```

How to bind only TabItems object from tabsList to TabsControl, is it possible without creating a separate list for TabItems?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedValuePath) and [`SelectedValuePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedValuePath) to use tabItem as name and as selectedValue.

Your `TabControl` would end up like this:

```cs
<TabControl Name="TabsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Tabitem" SelectedValuePath="Tabitem"/>
```

I wrote `Tabitem` because i don't know that the name of the property of type `Tabitem` of the object of type `TabObject` is called. if you access the item as tabObject.Item obviously you would have to write there only `Item`.

I hope I was helpful.